# Launch service at container startup

Tags: mysql, apache, docker, debian, dockerfile

I've already searched for ideas for my problem but I didn't found anything that I could use.
I have a dockerfile with MySql & Apache2 and I want them start when the container start too but I can't do it in the dockerfile with `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` because I want to put a `tail` to keep my container alive and I want to be able to go in bash mode directly with `run -it container bash` and if I put a tail in script or `CMD/ENTRYPOINT` it's impossible.

I tried to launch my services with `update-rc.d` but it doesn't work at all...

I tried to start MySql & Apache2 with a script with `ENTRYPOINT` and put the `tail` with `CMD` but I think it's impossible after a lot of try with differents dockerfile and script...

Here my dockerfile:

```
###
# Dockerfile db MySql
###

###
# Image
###

FROM debian:jessie

###
# Volume
###

VOLUME /usr/projet/volumes/volume_db

###
# Proxy & installations
###

RUN export http_proxy="myproxy:port" \
&& export https_proxy="myproxy:port" \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y vim \
&& echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password select root" | debconf-set-selections \
&& echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again select root" | debconf-set-selections \
&& apt-get install -y mysql-server \
&& apt-get install -y mysql-client \
&& service mysql start \
#&& service mysql stop \
&& echo "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/dbconfig-install boolean true" | debconf-set-selections \
&& echo "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/app-password-confirm password root" | debconf-set-selections \
&& echo "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/mysql/admin-user string root" | debconf-set-selections \
&& echo "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/mysql/admin-pass password root" | debconf-set-selections \
&& echo "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/mysql/app-pass password root" | debconf-set-selections \
&& echo "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/reconfigure-webserver multiselect apache2" | debconf-set-selections \
&& apt-get install -y phpmyadmin\
&& apt-get autoremove --purge

###
# Script startup
###

#COPY script_start /etc/init.d/

RUN update-rc.d apache2 defaults \
&& update-rc.d mysql defaults

###
# Variable env
###

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root

###

###
# Port exposition & cmd
###

EXPOSE 3306 80

CMD tail -F -n0 /etc/hosts
```

And there my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          script_start
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Boot services mysql apache2
# Description:       Boot services
### END INIT INFO

service mysql start \
&& service apache2 start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few pointers that might help you in your path -

1. Using MySQL and Apache2 in the same container is against
   container best practices. Consider dividing the two processes into
   separate containers, and connecting them with docker-compose.
2. Using `RUN` to start a service will do you no good, since it will run at build time but won't persist when you actually run the container. You should `ENTRYPOINT` for that, making sure that the script runs on container startup.
3. If you want to allow yourself connection into the container, you should use `docker exec` (which executes a command over a running container) over `docker run` (which tries to launch a new container from the same image)

Answer (score 1):

> I've already searched for ideas for my problem but I didn't found anything that I could use.

In almost all cases, you should only run a single process in a single container. Decoupling applications into multiple containers makes it much easier to scale horizontally and reuse containers. If that service depends on another service, make use of container linking.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#/run-only-one-process-per-container

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies, I had in mind to be able to go in bash mode directly with run...

So you're saying that normally I have to use `docker exec` to be able to modify my container in contrary to `run` that should be use to only deploy container ?

I'm going to do it with your advices, thanks ! :D